# Ошибка mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, sql

Сам запрос рабочий. Выводит напрямую из БД то что нужно, но почему-то на странице ошибку выдает. Кто-нибудь знает,как это можно исправить? Весь код страницы:

```
    <?php
        $page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? (int) $_GET["page"] : 1;
    
        $notesOnPage = 3;
    
        $from = ($page - 1) * $notesOnPage;
    
        $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");  
        $query = "SELECT `discription`, `author`, `data`, `tags`.`Name` FROM `quote`, `tags` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from, $notesOnPage";
        var_dump($query);
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $number = 0;
    
        while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
    ?>
    
    <div class="card news border-dark mb-3" style="min-width: 100%;">
        <div class="card-header">Quotes</div>
            <div class="card-body text-dark">
                <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-checker" id="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                <div class="limiter">                   
                    <p class="card-text">Автор: <?php echo $news['author']; ?></p>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['discription']; ?></p>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['data']; ?></p>
                    <div class="bottom"></div>
                </div>
                <label for="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" class="read-more-button"></label>
            </div>  
    </div>

<?php
        $number = $number + 1;
    }

    $select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `quote`");
    if (!$select) die ('Error'. mysqli_error($connect));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
    $count_post = $row [0];

    $pages_count = ceil ($count_post / $notesOnPage);
    //var_dump($pages_count);
?>
    <div class="pagination">
<?php

    for($i = 1; $i < $pages_count; $i++){
        echo "<a href =\"?page=$i\">$i </a>";
    }
?>
</div>  

<?php
    include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

Ошибка: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\quotes\index.php on line 23

Линия 23 - while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

Comment: что говорит отладка? напиши в пустой 17ой строке ```<?php var_dump($news) ?> ```
Что выводит?

Comment: @4kilograms да и так ясно что у него там.... вполне себе написано

Comment: Неё) Главное же не решить за нее задачу, а показать как решать их. Пусть дебажит код и ищет где косякнула

Comment: @4kilograms в дубликате всё написано...... можно ещё вот это подкинуть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482   (там про отладку и пр. тоже есть)   тогда точно больше ничего не нужно